# Get element data as string, without conversion

Tags: jquery

I want to get element data as string using simple html:

```
<div data-prefix="+43"></div>
```

and script:

```
$('#my_div').data('prefix'); /* Getting: 43 */
```

But I need `+` because it is a phone number. Already tried with `&#43;`, but script (or browser?) still makes conversion to number. Is there a way to avoid the conversion and take control of what kind of data we need?

I know I can get the text using:

```
$('#my_div').attr('data-prefix');
```

But I am asking is there some Javascript or jQuery method similar to:

```
$('#my_div').data('prefix', STRING); /* or */
$('#my_div').dataString('prefix'); /* or something else... */
```

EDIT:

If I inspect the DOM element, there I see that `element.dataset.prefix` has a correct value `"+43"`. Also, looking at Josh Crozier's comment, it looks like the jQuery itself does the conversion the way it likes.

Comment: The method similar to `.data('prefix')` that doesn't do type conversion is `.attr('data-prefix')` so you've just answered your own question

Comment: I just tested this out and `.data()` varies based on the versions.. `.data('prefix')` yields `+43` in v1.8.3+ and `43` in v1.7.2 and lower.

Comment: That is exactly what I was afraid of, thanks for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the jQuery documentation for [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

so the correct way is `$('#theId').attr('data-prefix');`

Comment: I see they also say `A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation`, which should mean - if we convert the number back to string it should be same. Looks like they do not care about the plus sign. I shall mark this as an answer, cause as far as I can see this is pure a jQuery issue (shall also remove Javascript tag, because dataset is correct).

Comment: @skobaljic - the problem is that `+43` is a valid number, so `"+43" == 43` equals true, and that's why jQuery converts it to a number, it does in fact not change the values representation.

Comment: They say that `"100.000" == 100`, but they do not do the conversion. As they fixed this in version greater than 1.7.2, think I am quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

i try it but i got "+43"

```js
$("#v").text($("#test").data('prefix'));
alert($("#test").data('prefix'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-prefix="+43" id ="test">asdf </div>
<a id="v"></a>
```

Comment: True, please look at Josh's comment above, I am on jQuery v1.7.2